# Error running Create table student on sql developer :CREATE TABLE students

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE students (
Year          NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
Semester VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT stu_sem_ck CHECK (semester IN ('1', '2', '3')),
department    VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
course_number NUMBER NOT NULL,
session       VARCHAR2(3),
first_name    NVARCHAR2(10),
Middle_name   NVARCHAR2(15),
last_name     NVARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
id            NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
area_code     VARCHAR2(3),
phone_number  VARCHAR2(7),
email_address NVARCHAR2(60),
Street1       NVARCHAR2(20),
street2       NVARCHAR2(20),
city          NVARCHAR2(20),
State_prov    NVARCHAR2(20),
country       CHAR(2),
postal_code   NVARCHAR2(15),
language      CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT student_pk PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

When runned on SQL devloper, Its gives me following errors

```
Error starting at line 2 in command:
CREATE TABLE students (
Year          NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
Semester VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT stu_sem_ck CHECK (semester IN ('1', '2', '3')),
department    VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
course_number NUMBER NOT NULL,
session       VARCHAR2(3),
first_name    NVARCHAR2(10),
Middle_name   NVARCHAR2(15),
last_name     NVARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
id            NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
area_code     VARCHAR2(3),
phone_number  VARCHAR2(7),
email_address NVARCHAR2(60),
Street1       NVARCHAR2(20),
street2       NVARCHAR2(20),
city          NVARCHAR2(20),
State_prov    NVARCHAR2(20),
country       CHAR(2),
postal_code   NVARCHAR2(15),
language      CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT student_pk PRIMARY KEY (id))
Error at Command Line:6 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE TABLE students (
```

Comment: Please highlight Codes with CTRL+K

Comment: ... or click the `{}` button in the question text editor input...

Comment: The way to "debug" this kind of problems is to remove one column after the other until the statement works. Then you know which part is causing the error. Once you have that, it's easy to find out what the real problem is. This is a skill you **have** to develop.

Answer (score 1):

`SESSION` is a Oracle reserved word, it is not allowed to redefine the meaning of reserved word.

Rename your column

```
session
```

to a name that is not a reserved word. You should be fine!

refer - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm

Answer (score 0):

SESSION is a reserved keyword in Oracle. But if you want to use it as a column name then  use double quotes. Therefore change

```
session       VARCHAR2(3),
```

to

```
"session"       VARCHAR2(3),
```

Otherwise just rename the column.

**Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf62d5/1)**

Answer (score 0):

1-Create student table with id(pk),fristname,lastname,adress,city,country
2-Add column phone
3-Remove column country
4-Remove table student

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).